# How is the pain of Osteoarthritis related to Lunar movements?

Tags: osteoarthritis

My mother has Osteoarthritis. Her pain in the knees and ankles increases to a great deal on full moon and new moon days, even though she spends those days like any other normal day in terms of physical activities. This occurs not only to my mother, but also occured to her father (my late grandfather) and many others in her family. Not only in her family, I see that some of my neighbours afflicted with Osteoarthritis also suffer from huge pain on full moon and new moon days.

Can someone explain biologically how this happens?